# Questions about SSD failure

Tags: ssd

I am looking into getting a new laptop at some point, and everyone is using SSDs these days. From a CS course I took a while ago, I learnt something about the possibility of a power failure causing the SSD to fail completely (probably was talking about STL). I want to consider the risk of this happening, and whether I should get a laptop that has SSD and HDD because of this issue. A few questions about this:

1. Do modern SSDs still have this issue? (If not, how would I go about checking whether a laptop model's SSD has this issue)
2. Can forcing the computer to shutdown by holding the power button trigger this failure?
3. Can running out of power during hibernation trigger this failure?

Comment: I got a top quality Lenovo commercial X1 ThinkPad just over 4 years ago. It came with a Samsung NVMe 1 TB SSD drive. 4-year warranty on all that. A good SSD drive like I got is good for sustained writes well beyond the life of the machine. No issues to this point. I replaced the 1 TB hard drives in my Lenovo ThinkCenter 2 years ago with 2 TB Samsung  drives. Samsung Magician says all is well.

Comment: If you machine is in hibernation then it’s actually turned off so it uses no power.  “Can forcing the computer to shutdown by holding the power button trigger this failure?” - This is a user defined action.  It’s impossible to answer this question

Comment: How is it a user defined action? I am refering to the forced shutdown that happens when you hold the power button down for several seconds. There have apparently bee reports of this failing ssds.

Answer (score 0):

The problems you are referring to may have been an issue in the earliest controllers but have been long solved.

It's overkill but if you are particularly worried, buy a name brand like Samsung or Crucial who have a lot of experience here. If that's still not safe enough get a pro or server class drive. Often one of the differentiators is these include supercaps to ensure there are no part writes.  A journalling filesystem like NTFS or ext4 or newer can also give you mind.

That said, disks fail. Sometimes catastrophically.  You still need to do backups. Cloud backups are automatic, easy and inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

Drives die every day.
HD and SSD, server-class and consumer, new and old.

The solution today is the same as it ever was... always have a backup (or three).